# LWC for Task management

Tags: lightning-web-components, tasks

I have a requirement for a Task manager in LWC, where the user can change certain fields in it, like who it's assigned to, and add comments, as well as mark it as complete. I'm aware Tasks are not supported by UI API, and I hace an apex method to get the tasks, but I'm having issues to display the fields in the LWC. If anyone has faced a similar challenge and can give me some tips, much appreciated. Thank you!

Here's my code

Apex

```
public class RelatedTasks {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getTasks(Id caseId) {
        
        System.debug('Id entrante: ' + caseId);
        Map<Integer, TaskInfo> taskMap = new Map<Integer, TaskInfo>();
        List<Task> tasks = [SELECT Subject, Owner.Name, CompletedDateTime, completadoPor__r.Name, ActivityDate, Description, Priority, Status 
                            FROM Task 
                            WHERE WhatId = :caseId 
                            ORDER BY Priority DESC];
        
        Integer taskCounter = 1;
        for(Task taskRecord : tasks) {
            TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo();
            taskInfo.Subject = taskRecord.Subject;
            taskInfo.AssignedTo = taskRecord.Owner.Name;
            taskInfo.DueDate = taskRecord.ActivityDate;
            taskInfo.CompletedBy = taskRecord.completadoPor__r.Name;
            taskInfo.CompletedDate = taskRecord.CompletedDateTime;
            taskInfo.Comments = taskRecord.Description;
            taskInfo.Priority = taskRecord.Priority;
            taskInfo.Status = taskRecord.Status;
            taskMap.put(taskCounter, taskInfo);
            taskCounter++;
        }
        String jsonTaskData = JSON.serialize(taskMap);
        System.debug('Cantidad de tareas ' + taskMap.size());
        System.debug('Mapa: ' + taskMap);
        return jsonTaskData;
    }
    
    public class TaskInfo {
        public String Subject { get; set; }
        public String AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public Date DueDate { get; set; }
        public String CompletedBy { get; set; }
        public Datetime CompletedDate { get; set; }
        public String Comments { get; set; }
        public String Priority { get; set; }
        public String Status { get; set; }
    }
}
```

LWC JS

```
tasksFunction() {
        getTasks({ caseId: this.coso })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Raw Response:', result);
    
            let jsonData = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log('Parsed JSON:', jsonData);
    
            if (jsonData['1'] && jsonData['1']['TaskInfo']) {
                this.tasksList = jsonData['1']['TaskInfo'];
                console.log('tareas', this.tasksList);
            } else {
                console.error('Data structure is not as expected.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
```

HTML

````
    <lightning-tab label="Ver sólo tareas de esta Etapa">
            
            <div class="tabset__content">
              
              <template for:each={tasksList} for:item="task">
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.Subject}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.Status}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.Priority}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.DueDate}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.CompletedDate}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.CompletedBy}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.Comments}</p>
                <p key={task.Id}>{task.AssignedTo}</p>
              </template>
        
            </div>
    
          </lightning-tab>
    ```
````

Comment: Which issues do you have displaying the fields? Could you paste the relevant code into your question? This would make it much easier to answer.

Comment: Is [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-display-task-whatid-related-field-on-lightning-page) helpful? Although for Aura, I think much can be learned from the answer. Have you considered a wrapper?

Comment: @FelixvanHove I've added my code.

Answer (score 0):

A few points ahead:

- The code shown has a Map<Integer, TaskInfo> - a Map to store TaskInfo objects. Maps with Integer keys are not the same as Lists / arrays. The LWC `for:each` works with arrays.
- The code does some serialization/deserialization when handing over data from Apex to Javascript. Salesforce does this for us. But we have to add [`@AuraEnabled`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_apex_auraenabled_annotation.htm) to the properties of our Wrapper classes to make this work.

If you use a List in Apex, add `@AuraEnabled` to the attributes of the Wrapper fields, and don't do any serialization/deserialization, the code already works. Your class:

```apex
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<TaskInfo> getTasks(Id caseId) {
        List<Task> tasks = [
            SELECT
                Subject,
                Owner.Name,
                CompletedDateTime,
                completadoPor__r.Name,
                ActivityDate,
                Description,
                Priority,
                Status
            FROM Task
            WHERE WhatId = :caseId
            ORDER BY Priority DESC
        ];
        List<TaskInfo> taskList = new List<TaskInfo>();
        for (Task taskRecord : tasks) {
            TaskInfo taskInfo = new TaskInfo();
            taskInfo.Subject = taskRecord.Subject;
            taskInfo.AssignedTo = taskRecord.Owner.Name;
            taskInfo.DueDate = taskRecord.ActivityDate;
            taskInfo.CompletedBy = taskRecord.completadoPor__r.Name;
            taskInfo.CompletedDate = taskRecord.CompletedDateTime;
            taskInfo.Comments = taskRecord.Description;
            taskInfo.Priority = taskRecord.Priority;
            taskInfo.Status = taskRecord.Status;
            taskList.add(taskInfo);
        }

        return taskList;
    }
    
    public class TaskInfo {
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Subject { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String AssignedTo { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public Date DueDate { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String CompletedBy { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public Datetime CompletedDate { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Comments { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Priority { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String Status { get; set; }
    }
```

Component code:

```javascript
tasksFunction() {
    getTasks({ caseId: this.coso })
      .then((result) => {
        this.tasksList = result;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  }
```

As you see, I've removed the `cacheable=true`, because from what I understand users might want to change the comment (Description) of tasks, or trigger a change of the Status; in that case the `cacheable=true` became a liability. Without, `tasksFunction` retrieves the latest data from Salesforce every time it is called.

I might have mislead you, when I spoke of wrappers in the earlier comment however. If changing the task Description or Status is all that is required, and nothing is to be done with the WhatId and WhoId fields (which are "polymorphic", i.e. nasty), you can use the Task as is. Forget about wrappers and just return a list of Tasks from Apex.

The markup of your component is of course just a start. If I were you, I'd not try to list the fields of each individual Task record in it. The code of the LWC could get longish and hard to maintain. I'd consider two options:

- The use of a [lightning-datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation) to achieve a rendering of the data quite similar to the "Open Activities" related list that can be included in the Case flexipage. One can even add two "Row Actions" for the update of the Description and Status fields. (But one has to do some honing of references in the data to display fields on the parent, e.g. the Name of the Owner - lightning-datatable does not support this out-of-the-box.)
- Creating a [custom child LWC](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/create-components-compose.html) that handles the details of an individual Task record. This would be a bit more work, but allowed a highly customized UI.

I hope this helps.